# Expectations and conditional probabilities with fair and unfair coins

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm working with a large bag of coins. $\frac{1}{3}$ are unfair with $p = \frac{11}{20}$ for heads, the other $\frac{2}{3}$ are fair. The coins are being pulled out uniformly at random. I'm trying to find out two things:

First, I'm trying to wrap my head around the events present.

To determine the expected number of heads/tails I get, I can define two $rvs$, $X_{unbiased}\sim Bin(n, p)$ and $Y_{biased}\sim Bin(n,p)$ and set a new $rv$ $Z = X + Y$. By the linearity of expectation, $E(Z) = E(X) + E(Y)$. However, I'm getting stuck with the proportionality of coins.

I know that $E(kX) = kE(X)$, but can I apply the proportionality to the events themselves? It would be a way of partitioning $Z$ as $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint and exclusive, so that $E(Z) = \frac{2}{3}E(X) + \frac{1}{3}E(Y)$?

From an intuitive perspective, this seems to make sense. If I'm considering the expected number of heads in six tosses of the coin the answer I get is $3.1$. This makes sense; we should expect to get more heads than tails as the coins are biased towards heads. I'm not entirely sure though. If I was to do this using probabilities (for example, the condition upon which I get $n$ heads in $n$ throws), I would have two events $A_{unbiased}$ and $B_{biased}$ with the probability of $N$ heads in $N$ throws denoted as $P(A\cup B) = \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^n$. Does this seem right?

The second issue I'm having is with determining conditional probabilities relative to this question. I know that a certain actor pulls a coin out and gets tails four times. I want to know the probability that this coin was fair. Although my first thought (and [a quick search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95643/you-observe-k-heads-out-of-n-tosses-is-the-coin-fair)) told me to try doing hypothesis testing, that isn't exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this one.

Comment: What are you asking, exactly. What is 3.1 ? Do you want to distinguish whether you have an unfair or a fair coin?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma 3.1 is the expected number of heads, given 6 tosses of a coin, when I select a coin uniformly at random from the bag. I'm looking more for a conditional probability for the second. The probability that, given four tails in six tosses of the coin, that I have an unfair coin. I'll edit my question to be more clear though, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H_6$ is the number of heads in 6 tosses: $$E(H_6) = E(H_6 | \text{biased coin})P(\text{biased coin}) + E(H_6 | \text {unbiased coin})P(\text{unbiased coin})$$

Both conditional expectations are binomial ones: $6p$ for the biased, 3 for the unbiased one. So we get $\frac{66}{20}\frac{1}{3} + 3 \frac{2}{3} = \frac{11}{10} + 2 = 3.1$ indeed.

The other one is more subtle, and involves Bayes' rule, I think.

You want $P(\text{biased coin} | \text{4 heads out of 6})$. Call the biased event $b$, so $P(b) = \frac{1}{3}$ as given. Then you want:

$$P(b | H_6 = 4) = \frac{P(b \text{ and } H_6 = 4)}{P(H_6 = 4)}$$

The upper probability equals $P(H_6 = 4 | b)P(b) = \binom{6}{4} p^4 (1-p)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3}$, which you can compute.

The lower one we need to condition again:

$$P(H_6 = 4) = P(H_6 = 4 | b)P(b) + P(H_6 = 4 | \text{not }b)P(\text{not }b) = \binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \binom{6}{4}\frac{1}{2}^6 \cdot \frac{2}{3}\text{.}$$

Now complete the computation.

Comment: I was trying Baye's theorem earlier, but I gave up on it due to some thought about independence...

I understand the upper probability, but shouldn't the lower equal probability equal $$ \binom{6}{4}p_b^4(1-p_b)^2 * \frac{1}{3} + \binom{6}{4}p_{ub}^4(1-p_{ub})^2 * \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Corrected again. 2 Should indeed be 4 in the binomial probability

Comment: Argh, my corrections are filled with errors...

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the bag is large probably indicates a situation comparable with "drawing with replacement". If some coins are taken out then that does not change the relation $1:2$ between unfair and fair.

If a coin is taken out and is thrown then the probability on heads is: $$p:=\frac13\frac{11}{20}+\frac23\frac{10}{20}=\frac{31}{60}$$
Doing that $n$ times makes you dealing with binomial distribution having parameters $n$ and $p$.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, but does that connect to the linearity of expectations? Can I extend the proportionality to the expected random variable? And what of the conditional probability, the real bugger?

Comment: If $H$ denotes the number of heads that show up by $n$ coins then my answer tells you its distribution. Also you can write $H=UX+BY$ where $U+B=1$ and $U=1$ if an unbiased coin is taken and $U=0$ otherwise. Then linearity of expectation gives you $\mathbb EH=\mathbb EU\mathbb EX+\mathbb EB\mathbb EY=\frac23\mathbb EX+\frac13\mathbb EY$. I have not looked at your second issue yet.